# Taking position on another symbol in a strategy (pine-script)

Tags: pine-script

in a strategy how can I take a trade on another symbol?
*for example my strategy analyzing EURUSD chart, and want take long position on GBPUSD.
how I would code that in Strategy.entry() to take position in another symbol?

Comment: Not possible. The strategy tester works only with the current chart.

Comment: I hope Trading View team will add this feature to the platform soon.